# Outlines on repeated backgrounds/images in mobile Chrome

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

[image]

In mobile Chrome there are faint lines at the edges of backgrounds and `border-image`s as seen in this screenshot (bottom of bricks and around the inside of green header.)

I've seen it mentioned on SO that backgrounds that get repeated (in my case the image has `repeat-x`) but I haven't seen the `border-image` case mentioned (in the screenshot the border has green in it then the `background-color` is set to the same green.)

Has anybody worked around this? I recently installed Android 4.4 on my phone and this bug goes all the way back to then. Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's the CSS for those elements:

```
#content { /* div the background is on */
        background-image: url('/media/top.png');
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-position: left top;
}
h1 { /* headings (green boxes */
        border: 30px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: #25552e;
        border-image: url('media/border.png') 33.3% round;
        color: white;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to post your current css for those elements?  May give us a good place to start.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added the CSS.

Comment: Is it possible that the thin line shown is actually part of your picture?

Comment: No, they definitely are not.